How to interpret dispersion estimated for a Poisson model?
Suppose I have the following data: $(N_i, x_i, \nu_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. I motivate this quickly from car insurance pricing. $N_i$ represents the number of claims, $x_i$ are some features I know and $\nu_i$ is some exposure (=time). For example: Over the course of half a year (i.e. $\nu_i = 0.5$) I observe two (i.e. $N_i = 2$) claims from a driver aged 35 and with a car which is 1 year old (i.e. $x_i = (35, 1)$, in this case my features include the driver age and the age of the car).
Given the data, I could choose the following modelling approach:
$$
N_i \overset{ind.}{\sim} \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda(x_i)\nu_i),
$$
hence the number of claims are modelled by independent Poisson random variables where the frequency function $x_i \to \lambda (x_i)$ needs to be modelled. Observe that the exposure is not modelled by $\lambda(.)$ but simply included in the model.
This example stems from a book I am reading, namely this. Now one can choose different modelling approaches for $\lambda(.)$, like GLM's, neural nets etc.
To assess the goodness of fit, the book discussed two ways: First, calculate the (in-sample) Pearson residuals given by
$$
\hat \delta_i^P = \frac{N_i - \lambda(x_i)\nu_i}{\sqrt{\lambda(x_i)\nu_i}}.
$$
According to my (Poisson) modelling assumption, these should be independent, roughly centred with unit variance.
Second, they define Possion Deviance residuals, given by
$$
\hat \delta_i^D = \mathrm{sgn}(N_i - \lambda(x_i)\nu_i) \sqrt{2N_i \left[\frac{\lambda(x_i)\nu_i}{N_i} - 1 - \log\left(\frac{\lambda(x_i)\nu_i}{N_i}\right)\right]}
$$
Lastly, the authors define two estimators for the dispersion of the model (here $q+1$ is the number of features in $x_i$):
$$
\hat \phi^P = \frac1{n-(q+1)} \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat \delta_i^P)^2
$$
and
$$
\hat \phi^D = \frac1{n-(q+1)} \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat \delta_i^D)^2 = \frac{D^*(\mathbf{N}, \lambda(.))}{n-(q+1)},
$$
where $D^*(\mathbf{N}, \lambda(.))$ is the Poisson deviance loss.
Question: I am not really getting why we look at these estimators for the dispersion. It is my understanding that dispersion tells me, if the model variance is close to its mean (I know that in a Poisson model variance is equal to its mean). What values of $\hat \phi^P$ and $\hat \phi^D$ would support my Poisson model assumptions? Especially, why is $\hat \phi^D$ a good way to look at this, how can I interpret its values and what values would support my hypothesis?
As you can see, it is not really clear to me why (especially $\hat\delta^D$) are something worth looking at. Are they simply there to tell me if my Poisson model choice is good or bad? I would be happy if someone more experienced could shine some light on my thoughts.
Thanks in advance!

You would typically use those test statistics to conduct a goodness-of-fit $\chi^2$ test after fitting the model. The tests return p-values for the null that the conditional distribution is Poisson. I would use those p-values rather than the value of the test statistics.
If you were mainly interested in the conditional mean, rejection is OK as long as the conditional mean is correctly specified and you use heteroskedastic errors to do inference. If you want to fit the whole distribution, then a rejection would be more concerning, and you should spend some time tweaking the specifications.
Here's an example in Stata:
. use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/dollhill3, clear 
(Doll and Hill (1966))

. poisson deaths i.smokes i.agecat, exp(pyears) irr nolog

Poisson regression                                      Number of obs =     10
                                                        LR chi2(5)    = 922.93
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -33.600153                             Pseudo R2     = 0.9321

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      deaths |        IRR   Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    1.smokes |   1.425519   .1530638     3.30   0.001     1.154984    1.759421
             |
      agecat |
      45–54  |   4.410584   .8605197     7.61   0.000     3.009011    6.464997
      55–64  |    13.8392   2.542638    14.30   0.000     9.654328    19.83809
      65–74  |   28.51678   5.269878    18.13   0.000     19.85177    40.96395
      75–84  |   40.45121   7.775511    19.25   0.000     27.75326    58.95885
             |
       _cons |   .0003636   .0000697   -41.30   0.000     .0002497    .0005296
  ln(pyears) |          1  (exposure)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: _cons estimates baseline incidence rate.

. estat gof

         Deviance goodness-of-fit =  12.13237
         Prob > chi2(4)           =    0.0164

         Pearson goodness-of-fit  =  11.15533
         Prob > chi2(4)           =    0.0249

. constraint 1 1.smokes#3.agecat = 1.smokes#4.agecat

. poisson deaths i.smokes#agecat i.agecat, exposure(pyears) irr constraints(1) nolog

Poisson regression                                      Number of obs =     10
                                                        Wald chi2(8)  = 632.14
Log likelihood = -27.572645                             Prob > chi2   = 0.0000

 ( 1)  [deaths]1.smokes#3.agecat - [deaths]1.smokes#4.agecat = 0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       deaths |        IRR   Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
smokes#agecat |
     1#35–44  |   5.736637   4.181256     2.40   0.017     1.374811    23.93711
     1#45–54  |   2.138812   .6520701     2.49   0.013     1.176691    3.887609
     1#55–64  |   1.412229   .2017485     2.42   0.016     1.067343    1.868557
     1#65–74  |   1.412229   .2017485     2.42   0.016     1.067343    1.868557
     1#75–84  |   .9047304   .1855513    -0.49   0.625     .6052658     1.35236
              |
       agecat |
       45–54  |    10.5631   8.067701     3.09   0.002     2.364153    47.19623
       55–64  |     47.671   34.37409     5.36   0.000     11.60056    195.8978
       65–74  |   98.22765   70.85012     6.36   0.000     23.89324    403.8244
       75–84  |   199.2099   145.3356     7.26   0.000     47.67693    832.3648
              |
        _cons |   .0001064   .0000753   -12.94   0.000     .0000266    .0004256
   ln(pyears) |          1  (exposure)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: _cons estimates baseline incidence rate.

. estat gof

         Deviance goodness-of-fit =  .0773491
         Prob > chi2(1)           =    0.7809

         Pearson goodness-of-fit  =  .0773885
         Prob > chi2(1)           =    0.7809

The first deviance goodness-of-fit test tells us that, given the model, we can reject the hypothesis that these data are Poisson distributed at the 1.64% significance level. The Pearson goodness-of-fit test tells us we can reject the hypothesis at the 2.49% significance level.
In the second model, we added age-smoking interactions and imposed the constraint that the smoking effects on third and fourth age categories are equal. The goodness-of-fit stats are now small, and the p-values are large, so we can no longer reject the null.

Thanks for the already great reply! I understand now that one mainly uses the two dispersion estimates as goodness of fit tests, given the Poisson assumption as the null. Two questions still arise: According to the authors of the book I mentioned, the deviance statistic is better than the Pearson one. This is because the deviance statistic also somehow includes the Poisson model assumption whereas the Pearson statistic is mainly used for Gaussian models. Why is the deviance statistic better under my model assumptions?

Second question: How do these dispersion statistics align with my understanding of dispersion of a model (Dispersion tells me how far off the mean and variance of a model are, for a Poisson model mean and variance are equal)?

There are many ways to define residuals in non-linear models and to test GoF and overdispersion. In my experience, many of these residuals tend to be highly pairwise-correlated. The tests also tend to agree. I would also favor the GLM approach. I don't have the book, so it's hard for me to follow the argument. Perhaps a new question with those details would be best.

Thanks! I accept your answer and think a little bit about your comments. Potentially, I open another question.
